# Encryption with Ruby on Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, encryption, sqlite

I'm doing an application in Ruby on Rails, version 3.0.10, where i'm allowing users to upload their own files, docs, pds etc and storing them in sqlite.

Does anyone know if i can use attr_encryted from https://github.com/shuber/attr_encrypted to encrypt all uploaded data?

thanking you....

Novice programmer

Answer (score 2):

We can implement encryption and decryption algorithm using Ruby On Rails

please find the url for the implementation :-

https://gurudathbn.wordpress.com/2015/02/04/aes-cipher-encryption-decryption-algorithms-using-ruby-on-rails/

example:- Encryption:- irb(main):007:0> AesEncryptDecrypt.encryption(‘gurudath’) => “rUPKObydUJd9cY9agm3Glw==\n”

Decryption:- irb(main):008:0> AesEncryptDecrypt.decryption(‘rUPKObydUJd9cY9agm3Glw==’) => “gurudath”

Answer (score 0):

You sure can.

I recommend the [more secure version](https://github.com/danpal/attr_encryptor) though.